Is bar.warp.sync needed if there is no divergence?
I am exchanging data between threads within a single warp in shared memory (storing then loading values). From PTX docs:

bar.warp.sync also guarantee memory ordering among threads participating in barrier. Thus, threads within warp that wish to communicate via memory can store to memory, execute bar.warp.sync, and then safely read values stored by other threads in warp.

In my use-case, I know that there is zero divergence in the store path. In other words, the stores are not conditional on any branch. All threads in the warp will be executing the same store instructions at the same time.
For such a case, is bar.warp.sync still necessary to guarantee memory ordering?

Related, possible duplicate: When can threads of a warp get scheduled independently on Volta+?. In particular, you still need the memory fence even if you trust future GPUs to not diverge, say, if some threads stall on a read while others go through cache (hypothetically)

divergence is only half the issue.  You also need to ensure visibility.  __syncwarp() serves both needs.  without the memory barrier, the compiler need not actually write to shared memory just because some other thread "needs" it.  And the divergence issue is not something you can properly ignore, regardless of what claims you wish to make about your code.  In short, your code is by definition broken, if you omit the barrier when exchanging data between threads in a warp via shared.  This blog makes the same statement.

One way is to use __shfl_sync instead to exchange data between threads in a warp, this does not suffer from racing condition because its sync is build in, it also does not need shared memory.
